# Maximum number of fields/columns in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, limits, fields

I'm considering learning and using MongoDB for a project, but I'm going to need to be able to store at least 1024 columns for the first part, and as many as 1048577 for the second. Does MongoDB have a limit on the number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends of [name space](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-a-namespace-in-mongodb) or the storage for each name of each field, MongoDB by default only available 16mb for each documents, including name space (field in documents, database name, collection name)

Read this: [limits namespaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces)

Comment: the namespace limit has _nothing_ to do with how many key-values one can stuff in a mongodb document.